# Can a man make video on YouTube?

Tags: quran, hadith

Allah says in the Quran (24:30,31) to man and woman to cast down their looks ,then how is it permissible for a man to make video on YouTube? Because when a man makes video on YouTube many woman are looking at the man.and when a woman makes video on YouTube people say it is not permissible for you to make video on YouTube even you are in hijab because many man are looking at you when you are making a video on YouTube.so,I say that the command is for both men and women.so my question is,how is it permissible for a man to make video on YouTube?

Comment: Tags are meant to help to categorize and find topics. Use relevant tags. Further Youtube or movie or TV is all a similar case.

Comment: I didn't mean that only on YouTube ,but specialy on YouTube.

Comment: Where is everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tafsir from Ibn Kathir of the ayah, that tells women to lower their gaze :

> وَقُل لِّلْمُوْمِنَاتِ يَغْضُضْنَ مِنْ أَبْصَارِهِنَّ

And tell the believing women to lower their gaze,

meaning, from that which Allah has forbidden them to look at, apart from their husbands.

(Some) scholars said that **it is permissible for women to look at non-Mahram men without desire**, as it was recorded in the Sahih that the Messenger of Allah was watching the Ethiopians playing with spears in the Masjid on the day of `Id, and A'ishah the Mother of the believers was watching them from behind him and he was concealing her from them, until she got bored and went away.

Source: Ibn Kathir

---

Also From [Islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/49038)

> Shaykh Muhammad ibn Saalih ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allaah have mercy on
> him) was asked:
>
> What is the ruling on a woman looking at a man on TV or looking in an
> ordinary fashion in the street?
>
> He replied:
>
> When women look at men, whether that is on TV or otherwise, one of the
> following two scenarios must apply:
>
> 1 – Looking with desire and enjoyment, which is haraam because of the
> evil and fitnah (temptation) involved
>
> 2 – Simply looking with no desire or enjoyment; there is nothing wrong
> with this according to the correct scholarly view, and this is
> permissible because it was proven that ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be
> pleased with her) watched the Ethiopians when they were playing in the
> mosque, and the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)
> was screening her from them, and he approved of her doing that.
>
> Women walk in the markets and look at men even when they are wearing
> hijab, so a woman may look at a man even when he does not look at her,
> on condition that there be no feelings of desire or fitnah
> (temptation). If there are any feelings of desire or fitnah
> (temptation) then it is haraam to look, whether the man is on TV or
> otherwise.